# Strange error related to \verb in section titles

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm writing a document about LaTeX, a sort of guide for my classmates. I've transported the here present practice of distinguishing code from text (backticks and 4-space indenting) by using `\verb` to show code. Trouble is, I have section titles which are package names, e.g. `\subsection*(\verb"thmtools")` coupled with `\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\verb"thmtools"}`. The result of that is the following error:

```
Runaway argument?
|\@empty \relax \hbox {}#I\catcode `\ \active \<let>-command \csname\endcsname
./Preambolo consigliato.tex:586: Paragraph ended before \HyPsd@@ProtectSpacesFi
was complete.
<to be read again> 
               \par 
l.586 ...ntsline{toc}{subsection}{\verb"geometry"}`
```

I therefore tried to construct an MWE to post here, writing:

```
\documentclass{report}  
\begin{document}  
\section*{\verb"mu"}  
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\verb"mu"}  
\tableofcontents  
\end{document}
```

only with that the error has changed to:

```
./mu26.tex:13: LaTeX Error: \verb illegal in command argument.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.13 \section*{\verb"mu"}
```

Stranger still, with `thmtools` as a title the error vanishes, whereas with `geometry` it reappears! I've gisted `.tex` and `.log` at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8235120, and `.aux`, `.out`, `.synctex.gz`, `.toc` and `.pdf` are blank or inaccessible. Why *is* this happening?

Comment: use `\texttt{mu}` instead. `\verb` cannot be inside an argument of a macro.

Comment: Uh-huh. Why can't it?

Comment: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=verbwithin

Answer (score 3):

For your MWE, `\texttt` is the proper approach, since your usage of verbatim did not include any special characters.  Even if it did, there are things like `\textbackslash` that can be used to simulate verbatim characters.

However, to stuff actual verbatim content into a section title, one can first put it into a box.  The problem there is that the box will not scale with the differing font sizes of the section title and table of contents.  Thus, scaling the verbatim box can overcome even this difficulty.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\begin{myverbbox}[\strut]{\verbA}
\verbatim $#%@^
\end{myverbbox}
\begin{myverbbox}[\strut]{\verbB}
\verbatim gjp with descenders
\end{myverbbox}

\tableofcontents

\section{This is \scaleto{\verbA}{\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}}

\verbA\ is the actual verbatim text\\
\scaleto{\verbA}{\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox} is the scaled verbatim text


\section{This is \scaleto{\verbB}{\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}}

\verbB\ is the actual verbatim text\\
\scaleto{\verbB}{\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox} is the scaled verbatim text

\end{document}
```

[image]